# How to use the calDAV protocol on a Flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, caldav

I'm a trainee and am learning about Flex, so I'm a total noob at this... My boss asked me to research the calDAV protocol for us to use in a calendar app we already have. I was trying to understand the Google API but I have no clue how to put this in our code. He wants me to make it possible to share events added to our calendar in Google Calendar or IPhone, for example. I'm starting to get desperate :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>It appears as the [Google CalDAV API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) is deprecated and it will likely go offline at some point soon.</s>

---

**Edit:** The [Google CalDAV API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) is not being deprecated, only the previous endpoint. Wording below has been amended to recommend Google's own API as an *alternative* method.

---

CalDAV itself is basically just a way to format information about calendar events in a specific way for communicating between services. It also defines how to send and receive this information. [Here's the CalDAV specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791) for more info.

If the requirement is to work with Google Calendar *but not specifically with CalDAV*, you could look at [v3 of their API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). It appears to be based more around JSON which should make it slightly easier to work with in AS3. There appears to be [AS3 libraries](https://code.google.com/p/as3googlecalendarlib/) out there for Google Calendar, but they seem to be outdated and unsupported, so it's likely that they won't work with the latest versions of the API.

The Google API relies on [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) calls. It basically means that you send HTTP `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` etc requests to [specified URLs on Google's servers](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/) to do specific tasks or to request data.

In order to use the API you need to [authorize your requests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth). The most common way to do this is to use OAuth 2.0 - in which your user grants your application access to its Google account, and in turn your application receives a token that needs to be sent with each request.

This isn't a complete answer to your problem, but I hope it outlines the process and gives you some useful links to read.

Comment: Why are you claiming that the Google CalDAV is going to go offline at 'some point soon'? The link you provide just states that the CalDAV API has a new *endpoint* and the old one is deprecated. CalDAV is not 'just a way to format information about calendar events', it is the RFC'd standard way on how this is done.

Comment: @hnh You are correct, it is only the endpoint that's deprecated. I got confused since their warning looks similar to what they do for deprecated APIs. I have amended my answer. The quote "just a way to format information about calendar events" is still true. Sure it's an accepted internet standard, but in order to explain what it *does* the sentence is still correct. It's just a specified way to format the calendar info along with instructions on how to send/request it.

Comment: Actually I got the information wrong... I need to share our calendar information with Google Calendar/iPhone/Outlook/etc, we have a database on Amazon, we need the information there to be shared with those other applications.